# Subscripting functions in C

Tags: c

I saw this code (pulled from device driver source, changed variable names, added comments)

What does the subscript [] do inside the `driver_funcs` static array of pointer to `void` ?

More importantly what's purpose of `DECLFUNC` here macro ?

```
#define DECLFUNC(x)  [DRIVER_##x - DRIVER_IOCTL_MIN]  f_##x
enum 
{
    DRIVER_IOCTL_MIN = 300,
    DRIVER_GET_PARTITION_STATUS = DRIVER_IOCTL_MIN,
    DRIVER_SET_PARTITION_MODE,
    DRIVER_GET_PROCESS_ID,
    //...
};


static int f_GET_PARTITION_STATUS( int a, int b, int c )
{
    //...
    return 1;
}

static int f_SET_PARTITION_MODE( int a, int b, int c )
{
    //...
    return 2;
}

static int f_GET_PROCESS_ID( int a, int b, int c )
{
    //...
    return 3;
}

static void *driver_funcs[] = 
{
    DECLFUNC(GET_PARTITION_STATUS),  
     //=> [0] f_GET_PARTITION_STATUS,  => *(f_GET_PARTITION_STATUS+0)   ???
    DECLFUNC(SET_PARTITION_MODE),    
     //=> [1] f_SET_PARTITION_MODE,   =>  *(f_SET_PARTITION_MODE+1)     ???
    DECLFUNC(GET_PROCESS_ID),        
    //=> [2] f_GET_PROCESS_ID,       =>  *(f_GET_PROCESS_ID+2)          ???
    //....
};
```

`driver_funcs` is used in normal way

```
func = driver_funcs[cmd - DRIVER_IOCTL_MIN];
func(1,2,3);
```

<sup>This code is compiled using gcc, if that matters (gcc extension ?). Also if its duplicate, please let me know I'll delete this post.</sup>

Comment: `driver_funcs` is just a table of entry points for the driver. Note that the code uses [C99 designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), which may be confusing if you're not familiar with them

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, I was aware of designated initializer, but was wondering where the heck is `=` sign. Joachim Pileborg tells GCC extension allows to ignore it.

Comment: Yes, that's covered on the page I linked to above: *An alternative syntax for this that has been obsolete since GCC 2.5 but GCC still accepts is to write ‘[index]’ before the element value, with no ‘=’.*

Comment: I didn't know this extension either and figured out by compiling the code with `-std=c99 -pedantic`. Both Clang and Gcc give nice warnings explaining the GNU extension, `warning: use of GNU 'missing =' extension in designator [-pedantic]` and `warning: obsolete use of designated initializer without ‘=’ [-pedantic]`, respectively.

Comment: @mafso Cool, looks like I missed `-pedantic` :$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature in the C99 standard, to be able to place items at arbitrary positions an in array initializer. See e.g. [this GCC manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

What it does is to place a function pointer for e.g. `GET_PARTITION_STATUS` at index zero in the array.

---

The C99 standard mandates that there should be a `=` between the index and the value, GCC as an extension of the language allows you to omit it.

Comment: But I don't see a `=` here in macro. Isn't that required ?

Comment: @P0W Ah, just saw that that part it's a GCC extension.